# Transient authentication error connecting to remote oracle db in db2ii

Tags: database, oracle, db2

I am trying to set up a connection to a remote oracle database in an IBM db2ii database.  The connection works, but the first I run a query or crate a nickname I get an authentication error.  All subsequent run succeed.  The query returns the column headers before the error and does actually run on the remote database, so it is not actually failing to authenticate.  I am connecting to an oracle 11 database (not supported) and do not encounter this problem connecting to an oracle 10 database.  However, there are a couple connections set up an working to oracle 11 from this database so I know it is possible.

If I create a duplicate of one that works, it does not work (see example below).  However, if I swap out the just user for the one in the nickname/user/server that does work, it starts working.  There does not appear to be any significant differences between the users in the oracle database (profile, roles, etc).  I imagine I'm just missing some configuration step for the user that doesn't show up in an export (exports are equivalent to what I have below) on the db2 side or the ddl on the oracle side.  Are there any DB2/Oracle database gurus out there who know what I might be missing?

```
[user@srvr1 ~]$ db2 "CREATE SERVER "MYAPPCM" TYPE ORACLE VERSION '10g' WRAPPER "NET8" OPTIONS (COLLATING_SEQUENCE  'Y' , CPU_RATIO  '.1' , DB2_MAXIMAL_PUSHDOWN  'Y' , FOLD_ID  'U' , NODE  'mysid' , PASSWORD  'Y' , PUSHDOWN  'Y' , VARCHAR_NO_TRAILING_BLANKS  'Y' )"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

[user@srvr1 ~]$ db2 "CREATE USER MAPPING FOR user SERVER "MYAPPCM" OPTIONS (REMOTE_AUTHID  'RMTUSR' ,REMOTE_PASSWORD 'rmtpw' )"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

[user@srvr1 ~]$ db2 CREATE NICKNAME "user"."MYTBLNICK" FOR "MYAPPCM"."MYSCHEMA"."MYTBL";
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL1101N  Remote database "MYAPPCM" on node "mysid" could not be accessed
with the specified authorization id and password.  SQLSTATE=08004

[user@srvr1 ~]$ db2 CREATE NICKNAME "user"."MYTBLNICK" FOR "MYAPPCM"."MYSCHEMA"."MYTBL";
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

[user@srvr1 ~]$ db2 quit
DB20000I  The QUIT command completed successfully.

[user@srvr1 ~]$ db2 connect to db2iiname

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUX 8.2.9
 SQL authorization ID   = user
 Local database alias   = DB2IINAME

[user@srvr1 ~]$ db2 "select count(*) from MYTBLNICK"

1
-----------
SQL1101N  Remote database "MYAPPCM" on node "mysid" could not be accessed
with the specified authorization id and password.  SQLSTATE=08004
[user@srvr1 ~]$ db2 "select count(*) from MYTBLNICK"

1
-----------
       7978

  1 record(s) selected.



[user@srvr1 ~]$ db2 quit
DB20000I  The QUIT command completed successfully.
```

Comment: many bugs have been fixed since around 2007 or 2008 when that Db2 v8.2.9 was being supported.  Time for workarounds perhaps.

Comment: What is in the diagnostic log at the time these errors happen? Might want to increase DIAGLEVEL temporarily too.